# Use a display value while preserving v-model binding in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, v-model

Sorry if this one is simple, but I just can't figure it out. I'm using Quasar Framework, but I think this is more of a Vue issue.

I have a multiple-select UI component, and a list of objects that I would like to display as the options. `v-model` will bind to the currently selected option.

Let's say I want to select an author from a list of authors. The component call looks like this:

```
<q-select
  v-model="currentAuthor"
  :options="authors"
  label="Select an Author..."
/>
```

The issue is that `authors` contains objects, not strings, for example

```js
this.authors = [
  { first_name: 'Roald', last_name: 'Dahl', id: 1}, 
  { first_name: 'J.R.', last_name: 'Rowling', id: 2}, 
]
```

Using `v-model` with the raw object just displays entries in the dropdown with the value

```
[object Object]
```

on each.

I don't want to map the authors array of objects to an array of strings, because when selected, I need the `id` attribute from each.

How can I set a display value for the dropdown (something like `${author.first_name} ${author.last_name}`) while still binding to the object with `v-model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `option-value` and `option-label` to map options value and label to object keys.

```
<q-select
  v-model="currentAuthor"
  :options="authors"
  label="Select an Author..."
  option-value="id"
  :option-label="(item) => item === null ? 'Null value' : `${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`"
/>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a million that had been bugging me for ages. I just needed `option-label`, I don't see what `option-value` is for?

Comment: `option-value` is for binding a specific key of the object to v-model, instead of the entire object. use it with `:emit-value="true"` or delete it, whichever fits you. Cheers!